# SQL Server replace characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to replace this number's `1234567891011` first and last four digits with stars.

How should I do it with replace function?

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring` function instead of `replace` and concatenate stars with "middle" part of your string:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max)
select @str = '1234567891011'

select '****' + substring(@str, 5, len(@str) - 8) + '****'
```

Output:

```
****56789****
```

Comment: Andy Thanks for reply, I will try solution and will  let you know.!

Comment: Andy can you please explain syntax of substring, so I can further modify as per my requirement what if I need to replace middle 4 digits.?

Comment: @AkkiBhogte See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx  for reference on this function.